# MeCabでTypeError（write() argument must be str...）

Tags: python

```
import MeCab
import sys

def morph_analysis(infile, outfile): # infileの文章を解析して，結果をoutfileに出力
  t = MeCab.Tagger(' '.join(sys.argv)) # 形態素解析器の変数（オブジェクト）を作成 
  fin = open(infile, 'r') # 解析対象のファイルを開く
  fout = open(outfile, 'w') # 解析結果を書き出すファイルを開
  fout.write(t.parse(fin.read())) # 読み込んで解析して書き出し
  fin.close() # ファイルを閉じる
  fout.close()
  return outfile

morph_analysis('new_data.txt', 'new_data2.txt')
```

エラーは以下の通りです。

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

英語版のスタックオーバーフローにも、同じ問題を抱えている方が多くいらっしゃるようなので参考にしたのですが、自分の場合どうやって参考にしたらいいのかがわからないため、質問させて頂きました。

よろしくお願い致します。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424379/how-to-fix-typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-none

Comment: 単純に文字列以外を`write()`メソッドに渡したせいです。`t.parse(fin.read())`の返り値が`None`になっているようです。MeCabのエラーではありません

Comment: dokubekoさんありがとうございます。英語版ではhiとかnoneなどを入れてみたらとのことだったのでnoneなどを入れて試したりしていました。`NameError: name 'none' is not defined` 結果的に上記の内容が帰ってきていました。`t.parse(fin.read())`を方法はわからないのですがプログラムのなかで機能を分割した方が良いという認識で合っていますでしょうか。

Comment: Pythonの基礎は学習されていますか？

Comment: 基礎は学習したのですが、忘れてしまったようなのでもう一度公式ドキュメントを確認してみます。

Comment: 渡しているfileの中身はtwitterの文章なのですが、絵文字等も混ざっていることがエラーの原因ということでしょうか。https://gist.github.com/anonymous/afdfb35eff975c8fb8dcc8838b7dfc8d

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04/Python 3.5.2/`ipadic-utf8`で`python3 filename.py`と実行しましたが正常に動作しました。エラーを再現するためにOSとPythonのバージョン、MeCabで使用している辞書を明示してください。絵文字が関係しているかはわかりません。`parse()`メソッドで`None`が返されているのが珍しいです。この質問は`mecab-python`の初心者が、解析時に返されるオブジェクトの型にハマったときのよいドキュメントになるかもしれません

Comment: python3 3.6.0 OS ubuntu 16.04 LTS MeCab ipadicです。

Comment: 辞書はmecab-ipadic-neologdでした ipadicも入っています

Comment: 実際に使われている辞書を特定するために、`sudo update-alternatives --config mecab-dictionary`を実行して実際にMeCabで使われている辞書を確認してください。また、`.py`を実行しているコマンドと引数を教えてください。 ---
 というのも、`Neologd`は引数で指定して使います。実行時の引数は`MeCab.Tagger(' '.join(sys.argv))`の行でとられていますが、実際に何を渡しているかわからないからです。何も渡してなければ`ipadic`を使っているかもしれません。この辞書は文字コードが`EUC`なので`UTF-8`のテキストの解析に使うとエラーになりますが、その場合は`UnicodeDecodeError`を出すので今回のケースの`None`が返ってる状況がまだよくわからないのです

Comment: すいません、わからない部分については後ほど調べてから返信致します。

Comment: 実行結果`There are 4 choices for the alternative mecab-dictionary (providing /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian).

  Selection    Path                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8   80        auto mode
  1            /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic        70        manual mode
  2            /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8   80        manual mode
  3            /var/lib/mecab/dic/juman         30        manual mode
  4            /var/lib/mecab/dic/juman-utf8    40        manual mode`

Comment: ipadic-utf8 が使われているようです。

Comment: .pyを実行しているコマンドというのは python ファイル名.pyで合っていますか？ 引数は特に指定していません。

Comment: 問題が特定できました。すいません。試していなかったこととして、`fin.read()`のなかに直接ファイルを挿入したところ、`TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str' `と出ました。stringデータがきちんと認識されていることがわかったので、試しに一部約300行を取り出して実行してみたところうまくいきました。ですが、全行を走らせようとすると掲載したエラーが発生します。元のtxtファイルに問題があったようです。お手数おかけしました。これから何行分までが動作するかなど探ってみます。

Comment: 元のファイルは約50000行分文章が入っているので、数が多すぎるとエラーが出るのかグーグルで調べてみます。

Comment: 「`fin.read()`の中に直接ファイルを挿入」の意味がわかりません。じぶんで問題が解決し正常に動いた場合、それまでにチェックした点や問題の要因、具体的に訂正して動いたコードを自己回答で投稿してください。同じ問題で困っている人のための情報になります。--- ファイルが大きくて動かないのは単にメモリ不足じゃないですか？　一行ずつ解析するテストコードを書いて量の問題か不正な文字の問題か切り分けるのがおすすめです

Comment: 申し訳ありません。変更した内容は以下になります。`(t.parse(fin.read()))` を`(t.parse(fin.read('ファイル名.txt')))`として実行し、`‌​TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str' `が出ました。メモリ不足が原因か確認と、1行ずつ解析するテストコードについて調べてみます。また追記致します。お世話になります。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: なにかわかったら是非回答にまとめてください。大量の投稿を解析したい人が同じようにハマるケースは多いと思うので

Comment: ご報告が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません. 以前こちらで質問をさせて頂きました. ありがとうございました. 結果として,原因がメモリ不足によるものだと結論づけました. Twitterの文章3000行以上を解析しようとすると上記のように"TypeError: integer argumen expected, got 'str'"と表示されます. 2999行までは対応できました. さくらのレンタルVPSの432MBのメモリプランを使用していました. 残念ながら, パスワードを保存したメモを紛失してしまい, (rootから変更済み)現在ログインができなくなってしまいました.

Comment: バックアップファイルも保存していないので, 残念ながらOSの再インストールを行いたいと思います. メモを探していたため投稿が遅くなりました. 申し訳ありませんでした.